# Huawei EMUI amenaza seguridad

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: captura de pantalla de aplicacion.]

De un dia para otro, solo en dispositivos Huawei y hasta ahora en versiones de EMUI

1. EMUI 10.0.0.185
2. EMUI 9.1.0.275
3. EMUI 1.0.0.203

La verdad no se por que pueda ser, los permisos que tiene la aplicación son los siguientes:

```
<!-- =================== P E R M I S S I O N S =================== -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Cual es la pregunta? Obtienes este mensaje pero es tu app? aporta detalles, revisar [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Todos esos permisos son necesarios? En otros dispositivos funcionan bien?

Comment: Lo que entendi es que te aparecio esto de un dia para otro. No soy experto en el tema pero quiza sea temas de firmas de certificados, es lo unico que se me ocurre. No creo que sea tema de permisos.

Comment: Efectivamente, en otros dispositivos funciona bien la app, es solo en dispositivos Huawei donde aparece esa alerta, esa aplicación ya esta en la PlayStore desde el 06/04/2020, he creado otras 2 aplicaciones similares, mismos permisos solo cambian los colores de las vistas y el logo y estas no tienen esa alerta, la verdad no tengo idea por que aparece esa alerta en esa aplicación.

Comment: quite los permisos "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" y "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" y la alerta ya no aparece, PERO, tengo 2 aplicaciones iguales a esta, que estan en PlayStore, con los mismos permisos y no hay alerta, todo muy rato

Answer (score 0):

Ciertamente los huawei son un poco "diferentes" con respecto a las demàs marcas, en el caso de este tipo de dispositivo algunas versiones actuales contienen un "anti virus" el cual determina si la aplicaciòn contiene un virus, por lo tanto no en todos los Huawei sucedera esto.

En algunas ocasiones es solo un falso positivo! ya que he visto el mensaje incluso en aplicaciones sencillas.

el mensaje en inglès es:

"my app appears to be infected. Immediate uninstallation is advised"

Si estas seguro que tu aplicaciòn no tiene un virus, solo da clic en el botòn "IGNORAR",

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en realidad serà un poco dificil lidiar con este detalle, puedes revisar màs informaciòn en este thread:

https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/why-my-compiled-app-with-trojan-app-has-virus/1607/36

Comment: quitando el permiso "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" la alerta deja de aparecer, nose por que segun huawei mi app tiene virus solo por tener ese permiso.

Comment: Seguramente determina que tu aplicación puede escribir a disco! , es algo sin sentido pero la heurística que ellos definen en tu antivirus es la que determina si tu app tiene o no virus, estos Huawei son un poco raritos :|